# Remove phrases in Array from string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to remove some phrases from a string in Ruby. The phrases are defined inside an array. It could look like this:

```
remove = ["Test", "Another One", "Something Else"]
```

Then I want to check and remove these from a given string.

"This is a Test" => "This is a "
"This is Another One" => "This is "
"This is Another Two" => "This is Another Two"

Using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rail 3.2.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ary = ["Test", "Another One", "Something Else", "(RegExp i\s escaped)"]
string.gsub(Regexp.union(ary), '')
```

[`Regexp.union`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union) can be used to compile an array of strings (or regexpes) into a single regexp which therefore only requires a single search & replace.

```
Regexp.union ['string', /regexp?/i] #=> /string|(?i-mx:regexp?)/
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest (but not most efficient):

```
# Non-mutating
cleaned = str
remove.each{ |s| cleaned = cleaned.gsub(s,'') }

# Mutating
remove.each{ |s| str.gsub!(s,'') }
```

More efficient (but less clear):

```
# Non-mutating
cleaned = str.gsub(Regexp.union(remove), '')

# Mutating
str.gsub!(Regexp.union(remove), '')
```